# RequestDispatcher forward vs RequestDispatcher include

Tags: java, servlets

Can anyone explain RequestDispatcher forward method and RequestDispatcher include method difference with live example also when we use RequestDispatcher forward and RequestDispatcher include with proper example?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google returns this example:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-request-dispatcher-and-how-do-i-use-it.html

And I think it aptly answers your question, including examples.